# Determining whether a given set can be an image of continuous function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, functions, continuity

The problem asks as, whether there exists a continuous function $f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ an image of which is set:

- $[0,1)$
- $(0,1]\cup[2,3]$
- $\Bbb{Q}$

So - for $[0,1)$ you can see that you can create function $f$ for which $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x) = 1$, and from $-\infty$ to some finite number it is constant $f(x)=0$ and than you can make a "smooth", parabolic transition between $0$ and $1$. For the second and third set you kinda see that it's not possible, as there is a gap between every rational number and between $1$ and $2$. But how to prove such things formally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second and third contradict the intermediate value theorem.

For the first one, i will give you an example with image $(0,1]$: $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x^2+1}$. I think you are capable of adjusting this to $[0,1).$

Comment: +1, even though one could think of topological obstructions rather than analytical ones.

Answer (score 3):

(topological) **Hint**:

$(0,1]\cup[2,3]$ and $\mathbb Q$ are both not connected.